# Load multiple waypoints using MySql and PHP on Google Maps v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm with a project on Google Maps v3.

On my project I can add multiple waypoints and save them on my database.

The problem is that I can't load this waypoints on map.

I have two projects.

[This][2] is the project that save the waypoints to database
And [this][3] is the project that load this waypoints.

The problem is that when I do multiple waypoints it only load the first waypoint (one Point "A" and one Point "B".

I need to make that all waypoints load at sametime on the map, on second project (loady.htm)
I will post my resumed code of index.htm, load.htm and the php script.

Remembering, I can save the waypoints to the database, but I can't load them.

Edit: Print of the saved table.

Comment: To me this isn't an issue of PHP/msql/ajax. It's an issue with how you're using google maps API. Not that I have an answer, I'm just making a note of why I'm removing the PHP, MySQL and AJAX tags.

Comment: I'm not your guy, friend! (Sorry, had to make the South Park reference)

Comment: I think that's impossible, because nobody answered my question =p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Google provides an example to load several waypoints:

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3#populatetable

Comment: Tried, but don't worked =/, my problem, is on the code, I can save to the database